# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'orbit'

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have been messing around with the orbit (zurb-foundation). I want to customize the slideshow  and I am getting an annoying error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'orbit'"
It looks like foundation.orbit.js script is not definet. Another weird thing is in this script the function starts with ;(function ($, window, document, undefined) is it normal the ';' ?
Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title> - Welcome to Foundation</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="/Content/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/foundation/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/foundation/foundation.mvc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/foundation/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <meta class="foundation-data-attribute-namespace">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-xxlarge">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-xlarge">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-large">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-medium">
    <meta class="foundation-mq-small">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 columns large-centered">
        <section class="full-grid">
            <div id="travelled-places">
                <img class="border" src="/Content/images/landing/canada-national-park.jpg" alt="Canada National Park" title="Canada National Park" data-thumb="~/Content/images/landing/canada-national-park.jpg" style="display: block; z-index: 1;">                    
                <img class="border" src="/Content/images/landing/china-gardens.jpg" alt="China Gardens" title="China Gardens" data-thumb="~/Content/images/landing/china-gardens.jpg" style="display: none; z-index: 1;">
                <img class="border" src="/Content/images/landing/grand-canyon.jpg" alt="Grand Canyon" title="Grand Canyon" data-thumb="~/Content/images/landing/grand-canyon.jpg" style="display: none; z-index: 1;">
                <img class="border" src="/Content/images/landing/hawaii.jpg" alt="Hawaii" title="Hawaii" data-thumb="~/Content/images/landing/hawaii.jpg" style="display: none; z-index: 1;">
            </div>                
            <div class="cn-bar">
                <div class="cn-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="cn-nav-next">
                        <span>Previous</span>
                        <div style="background-image:url(/Content/images/landing/china-gardens.jpg);"></div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="cn-nav-next">
                        <span>Next</span>
                        <div style="background-image:url(/Content/images/landing/hawaii.jpg);"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.alert.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.slider.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.tab.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
    <script>
    //$(document).foundation();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#travelled-places').orbit({
            animation: 'fade',                  // fade, horizontal-slide, vertical-slide, horizontal-push
            animationSpeed: 800,                // how fast animtions are
            timer: true,             // true or false to have the timer
            advanceSpeed: 4000,          // if timer is enabled, time between transitions 
            pauseOnHover: false,         // if you hover pauses the slider
            startClockOnMouseOut: false,     // if clock should start on MouseOut
            startClockOnMouseOutAfter: 1000,     // how long after MouseOut should the timer start again
            directionalNav: true,        // manual advancing directional navs
            captions: true,              // do you want captions?
            captionAnimation: 'fade',        // fade, slideOpen, none
            captionAnimationSpeed: 800,      // if so how quickly should they animate in
            bullets: false,          // true or false to activate the bullet navigation
            bulletThumbs: false,         // thumbnails for the bullets
            bulletThumbLocation: '',         // location from this file where thumbs will be
            afterSlideChange: function () { }    // empty function 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've missed the JS files: see http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

Comment: I had them in my code but I forgot to add them here in the post. I updated it just now.

Comment: Read the link that I posted as you're including things wrong and not initialising the foundation JS.

Comment: Just taking another look at your code, as you're specifying each plugin separately that's fine. You need to uncomment this `$(document).foundation();` to load foundations plugins before you can use them. Then you need to call `orbit` correctly. Scroll down to the JS part of this page http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Comment: So, to I have to call foundation() twice like this?:
$(document).foundation();
$(document).foundation({
    orbit: {
        animation: 'fade',
  ....
or should I call the foundation for the orbit element?:
$('#scope').foundation();

Comment: It's not calling it twice. The first call `$(document).foundation();` initialises foundation. The second call is for orbit. You always have to initialise foundation to use the plugins even if you're not making any other changes.

Comment: I am making some progress, I got rid of the error. Thanks

Comment: @DAC84 can you write your comment as a answer in order for me to mark it as answered? Or is there a way to promote a comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

1. You need to uncomment `$(document).foundation();` to initialise foundations plugins before you can use them.
2. You're not calling `orbit` correctly, it is called on the `document` and then by adding the `data-orbit` attribute to your `<div id="travelled-places">` element like so:

   ```
   $(document).foundation({
       orbit: {
           ... // your options
       }
   });
   ```

See [Foundations Orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) documentation for further reference.